# Interesting driving circuit of a voice coil actuator

Tags: h-bridge, feedback, closed-loop, 741-opamp

I have an interesting circuit to drive the voice coil stage of an old acoustic microscope. I am struggling to understand what the different functions of the opamps in this circuit are.

The circuit looks like this:

[image]

On the top left side, the input signals are connected to the board. At the bottom right side, the output signals are connected to the voice coil. The stage has an optical position sensor which means that the input signals to the board (GGM, ENX) are already the result of a closed loop system.

I know that the current of the coils is produced by the H-bridge at the top right. I am struggeling to understand what the opamps part is necassary for and why there is another feedback system with N1.3.

Comment: N1.3 looks like a gain for the feedback, N1.1 looks like a PI compensator, N1.2 like an inverter to make mirror image control signal to the opposite half bridge

Comment: If the voice coil is off to the RHS, then R3 is a current sensor, so N1.3 may be providing current feedback, or possibly short circuit protection. If it's working in its linear range, current feedback so that the input V controls the drive current.

Comment: Thank you for the input. So basically the signal on "ENX" is defining the output current. Any idea what the intence of the "GGM" signal input is? Is it maybe an output?

Comment: Well it's obviously an output, but I've no idea what for.